# How to include external javascript component in aura or LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, aura

I'm currently working to include a javascript component with in the salesforce custom aura or LWC. But i'm literally confused where to pick it up. Please guide me to handle.

As per @sfdcfox advise i have added my external js as a static resource

My code:

```
<aura:component >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.Widget}"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
</aura:component>
```

When i try to preview the component is showing blank page. When i check the console i'm getting below errors.

[image]

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
> header is present on the requested resource.

I'm confused did i miss anything here.

Comment: Could you include your component's JS?  I think we're missing a part of the picture here.

Comment: The external JS file (which you added to the static resource) could be referring to some other external JS causing this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot inject scripts in this way. This is a security feature enforced by Locker Service/Lightning Web Security. You can only import scripts from Static Resources, and only via `loadScript`/`ltng:require`. See [Use Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) (LWC) and [Using External JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm).

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox i have tried it but the component is not displaying, when i check console i'm getting this exception . Refused to connect to 'https://client.xxxxx.next.com/staging/parent-injected-latest/parent-end.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' https://api.bluetail.salesforce.com https://staging.bluetail.salesforce.com https://preprod.bluetail.salesforce.com https://app.proposify.com blob: *.visualforce.com https://apty--dev--c.documentforce.com".

Comment: @Pavantej Exactly what I'd expect to see. You must use a static resource to host your script.

Comment: Yes, @sfdcfox  i have added my external js as static resource but i'm getting content security policy issues. I have updated my question Could you please go through it once